# File path incorrect when trying to play a recorded file

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an AVAudioRecorder:

```
let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as! String
let soundFilePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("sound.caf")
let soundFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath)

do {

        try audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: soundFileURL, settings: recordSettings as! [String : AnyObject])
        audioRecorder?.prepareToRecord()

    } catch let error as NSError {

        print("audioSession error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        audioRecorder = nil

    }
```

Then record, and save the file URL into core data, because I can't save URL to core data so I used string for the file path instead:

```
content.setValue(path, forKey: "fileDirectory")
```

The recorder has certainly created a file because it shows up in the table view. But it can't play, so I checked if the file exists at provided file path:

```
if audioRecorder?.recording == false {

        let inspirationString = inspirations[indexPath.row].valueForKey("fileDirectory") as! String
        let fileDirString = NSURL(string: inspirationString)!

        if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(inspirationString) {

            print(inspirationString)
            print("The file doesn't exist.")

        }
```

It prints this in the console:

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/42E96A6F-D16C-4AB4-84FC-315109AC3374/Documents/sound.caf

The file doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you verified that the file actually exists?

Comment: How do I verify? The file exists in core data because it shows in my table view and has a name, but when I click on the cell, it can't play.

Comment: I think there might be some problem with the file path, I converted it from sting to url, then url to string, there might be something wrong with the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code snippet, it worked for me:

```
if audioRecorder?.recording == false {

    let inspirationString = inspirations[indexPath.row].valueForKey("fileDirectory") as! String
    let fileDirString = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: inspirationString)!

    if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(inspirationString) {

        print(inspirationString)
        print("The file doesn't exist.")

    }
}
```

Basically, `NSURL(fileURLWithPath: inspirationString)!` works for local files rather than `NSURL(string: inspirationString)!`